# VBA - Trying to refresh data every second and also store that value in a new cell every refresh

Tags: excel, vba, simulation, timing

I am trying all sorts of ways to refresh my random integers in B4:B419 and at the same time store the output of F1 in a new cell at the end of column F.  Running RunAll only refreshes the data in B4:B419 and does not continuously paste the new values of F1.

```
Sub Calculate_Range()

    Sheets("Shoe Simulation").Range("B4:B419").Calculate
    
    Dim last_row As Long
    
    last_row = Sheets("EV").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Sheets("EV").Range("F1").Copy
    
    Sheets("EV").Cells(last_row + 1, "F").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    

End Sub



Sub Timeing()

    Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 1, Now), "Calculate_Range"
    
End Sub

Sub RunAll()

    Call Calculate_Range
    
    Call Timeing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but are you trying to have the code run continuously non stop?

The reason why it isn't running continuously is because the RunAll sub only calls each function once.
It calls calculate_Range, which runs once and then it calls Timeing() which also has Calculate_Range run once.
If you add `Call Timeing()` to the end of your Calculate_Range sub, then it will loop between the 2 continuously. Please note though that this will effectively make an infinite loop.

Comment: The other way to do this would be to add `Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 1, Now), "Calculate_Range"` to the end of your Sub Calculate_Range()